# change # symbol to #! vue js router

Tags: vue.js

my client wants to use AJAX crawling
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification
(I know that it is deprecated But he wants it to use because of another search engine that still support it such as yandex.ru)

So I want to translate http://example.com/#/card/card_slug?category=car

to http://example.com/#!/card/card_slug?category=car

How do I do this with vue-router?

Answer (score 1):

Hashbang was used [before vue-router 2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/1.0/docs/en/options.md#hashbang), but no longer supported now.
However you can try this workaround.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: '/#!/',
})
```

See discussion [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/885).